# Getting crashed when NSdictionary or NSString values into UILABEL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

```
-(void) httpDataDidFinishLoadingWithData:(NSData *)theData
{
    m_activityLoaded=NO;
    temp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dataLoader httpData]
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"TEMP IS TEMP %@", temp);

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"location"];

    NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict1 = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"wind"];


    NSDictionary *dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict2 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"direction"];

    NSDictionary *dict3 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict3 = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"atmosphere"];

    NSDictionary *dict4 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict4 = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"condition"];
    NSDictionary *dict5 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict5 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSDictionary *dict6 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict6 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"code"];
    NSDictionary *dict7 = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict7 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"temperature"];

    temperatureLabel.text = [dict4 objectForKey:@"temperature"];
}
```

Crash occurs at `temperatureLabel.text = [dict4 objectForKey:@"temperature"];`

I dont know man, Data is exactly printed in the console, but crashing at UILABEL(temperatureLabel). Help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: Just a small tip, don't alloc and init the `NSDictionary` when you are going to assign an other value to it. You are now just leak memory.

Comment: error msg is [__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68ac960

Comment: It won't help you with the crash, but you really need to understand that you are leak memory. You don't need to alloc and init all those `NSDictionary`. You are assigning `NSDictionary` to the variables when you use the `objectForKey:`.

Comment: I removed that allocation, but still crashing man ,,,, :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look at the error you are getting it is telling you that the object return for the key `temperature` is not a `NSString` or `NSDictionary` but a `NSNumber`.

Give this a try:

```
-(void) httpDataDidFinishLoadingWithData:(NSData *)theData {
    m_activityLoaded=NO;
    temp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dataLoader httpData]
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"TEMP IS TEMP %@", temp);

    NSDictionary *dict = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"location"];
    NSDictionary *dict1 =  [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"wind"];
    NSDictionary *dict2 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"direction"];

    NSDictionary *dict3 = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"atmosphere"];
    NSDictionary *dict4 = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"condition"];
    NSDictionary *dict5 = [dict4 objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSDictionary *dict6 =  [dict4 objectForKey:@"code"];
    NSNumber *temperature = [dict4 objectForKey:@"temperature"];

    temperatureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", temperature]; 
}
```

You might want to look at [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for formatter the temperature with something like: °F or °C.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary contains an `NSNumber` instance and you are assigning that to a property of type `NSString`. The crash message is your tip off there. Use `stringValue` or some other way to get the number's data into string form.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your object is of NSString class?

Try putting in something like:

```
if([[dict4 objectForKey:@"temperature"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   NSLog(@"lalala");
```

If it does not get logged to the console it means that your object is not an NSString and you could try something like:

```
temperatureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict4 objectForKey:@"temperature"]];
```

You should change the %@ according to the kind of object you have stored in your dictionnary.